# How is the GenBank used in typical biological research?

Tags: sequence-analysis, sequence-alignment

How is the [GenBank](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/) used in typical biological research? According to the GenBank statistics, the database contains about 100 million sequences. I find it difficult to understand why is all that data needed. To make the question less broad, what are the most common use-cases? Check if someone already sequenced DNA of some plant or animal?

Comment: Can you please specify your question? At the moment its quite broad...

Comment: Any better now? I would be interested what are for example the three to five most common use-cases.

Comment: This is a bit like asking what are the top uses of a library. The reasons are myriad.

Comment: You need to do some basic research on Genbank.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com). Enter "Genbank" into the search field and press return. Limit the results to 2013 and later (left side of the results).  Skip the few entries that say only "GenBank." Browse through the pages and pages of search results to get a feel for the many ways that GenBank is used in scientific research. It's used from everything for phylogenetic analysis (relationships among organisms) to determining protein structure and so much more.